# “cannot get automation extension” error with chrome version: 57.0.2987.98

Tags: google-chrome, automation, protractor, angularjs-e2e

chrome version : **57.0.2987.98 m (64-bit)**

```
"protractor": "4.0.11",
"protractor-console-plugin": "0.1.1",
"protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.6",
"protractor-notify-plugin": "1.0.0",
```

protractor failed to launch chrome with the following error:

```
 unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 10.10 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
```

Comment: Can you unintsall and re-install chrome browser and check it that resolves the issue

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are using incompatible versions of `chromedriver=2.26.436362` and `chrome=57.0.2987.98`.

As per [Chrome driver release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.28/notes.txt) the error is fixed in ver 2.28 so you should upgrade your Chrome driver (or downgrade the Chrome browser).

upd: if you use `angular/webdriver-manager` to run Selenium server then you can achieve this by running the following commands:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=2.28
webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome=2.28
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use this as a workaround

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.28
node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start --versions.chrome 2.28
```

Works for my team. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading your protractor version to 5+ should do it. I got the same error, upgraded from 4.0.14 to 5.1.1, and now all my UI tests are passing again.

It seems that protractor doesn't start grabbing the latest version of the chrome driver until Protractor version 5.0, so when you upgrade to a version of Chrome that's incompatible with protractor's chrome driver, it will break your tests in this fun new way.

Source: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: If updated to 5+, will it support to earlier version of chrome?

Comment: Thanks - our CI server was running webdriver-manager update every time it ran our tests and yet still not upgrading to the latest chromedriver - pushing protractor up to v5+ as you suggest resolved this :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be because `webdriver` failed to deal with 3-party `Chrome` extension.

You can try to set below `capabilities` in your `conf.js` file to disable extensions usage:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'chrome',
  'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['--disable-extensions']
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try to remove specified in exception log extension. Check this https://www.timeatlas.com/uninstall-chrome-extensions

Comment: This actually worked for me. Chrome version: 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit) - ChromeDriver version: 2.28.455517